# Building OpenCV 4.0 for Android: Cannot Include <iostream>?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to build OpenCV from source for **Android** library. However, the following error occurs:

```
[ 18%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_unix.c.o
/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/src/3rdparty/libtiff/tif_stream.cxx:29:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
```

(By the way, such error seems to happen whenever it tries to include iostream, and I just paste one typical error since everyone is same.)

My build command:

```
/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/cmake-3.15.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../src/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake \
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared \
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE=c++_shared \
-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=27 \
-DANDROID_SDK=/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-sdk \
-DANDROID_NDK=/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64 \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
-DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=OFF \
-DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF \
-DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DWITH_MATLAB=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
../src \
&& make -j4
```

Thanks for any advice!!

**EDIT**: compile with `-j1`

```
[ 13%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_stream.cxx.o
/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/src/3rdparty/libtiff/tif_stream.cxx:29:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/build.make:582: recipe for target '3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_stream.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_stream.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:293: recipe for target '3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

About where is the iostream: in location `d:\OpenCVBuild\android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\`, there a lot of files, including the `iostream` (however without any extension, not `iostream.h`).

By the way, this is some info of cmake:

```
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    NEON
--       requested:                 NEON FP16
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-g++  (ver 4.9.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/platforms/android-27/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=27   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections   -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/platforms/android-27/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=27   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections   -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/platforms/android-27/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=27   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections   -fvisibility=hidden -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/android-ndk-r16b-linux-x86_64/platforms/android-27/arch-arm64 -funwind-tables -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=27   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections   -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -Wl,--gc-sections
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -Wl,--gc-sections
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m log
```

---

EDIT2: I tried to use `gnustl`, i.e.

```
-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static \
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE=gnustl_static \
```

but with error:

```
[ 69%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/utils/logtagmanager.cpp.o
/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/src/modules/core/src/utils/logtagconfigparser.cpp: In static member function 'static std::string cv::utils::logging::LogTagConfigParser::toString(cv::utils::logging::LogLevel)':
/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/src/modules/core/src/utils/logtagconfigparser.cpp:301:16: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
         return std::to_string((int)level);
                ^
/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/src/modules/core/src/utils/logtagconfigparser.cpp:303:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
```

Comment: I have no experience of Android development but I'm going to ask the obvious questions. Do you have iostream somewhere on your system? And if so where is it? What compiler are you using?

Comment: I have no idea (as I said I don't know Android). But there are two possibilities, either the iostream header file is missing from your computer, or it's there but the compiler is looking for it in the wrong place. Knowing which of these is true is the first step to solving the problem. If the first is true then you have to install the missing header files somehow, if the second is true then you have to understand how your compiler finds header files and fix whatever problem is causing it to look in the wrong place.

Comment: This might seem complicated, but if you are going to do development you have to understand the tools you are using (especially when things go wrong). I guess you need to read some background material for developing on Android. These aren't simple systems, you have to understand them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`include <iostream>` is available only in C++ language, and not C. Those are different languages (even tough they are very similar).

You code is saved into a C file

```
[ 18%] Building C object 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeFiles/libtiff.dir/tif_unix.c.o
/mnt/d/OpenCVBuild/src/3rdparty/libtiff/tif_stream.cxx:29:20: fatal error: 
iostream: No such file or directory
#include <iostream>
```

Are you including a C++ file into a C file? Please re-run the code with `make -j1` to get a proper error (messages will not get interlaced between compilation threads).

Comment: Ah! Good point! It is actually OpenCV source code, which I do NOT modify... Let me have a look. Thanks!!

Comment: However, it is a .cxx file, not a .c one... So what should I do? Thanks so much!

Comment: start with a `make -j1` output and you will see the problem

Comment: OK let me try it!

Comment: I edited the question, with info by -j1 and the `include` dir

Comment: I solved it by finding that the include dirs generated by OpenCV toolchain.cmake is wrong... I manually modified it and it can include now. However, it has another problem now... see modified question